# Let the Angular Service Worker work only for Angular files

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I have an Angular 8 application with working together another application (old version of the app. I keep developing the new version and they should continue to work together). I know Angular has path prefixes `['/path1', '/path2', '/path3']`. All other paths of using for api or old version app (for example, `['/api/*', '/*']`).

I want to use Service Worker and the Service Worker just caches Angular files.

#### Angular paths example:

Application route:

- `/path1/*`
- `/path2/*`
- `/path3/*`

And all Angular source file:

- `/index.html`
- `/main.(_hash_).js`
- `/common.(_hash_).js`
- `/polyfills.(_hash_).js`
- `... *(all prod compiled angular files)*`
- `/assets/*`

#### Other Paths example:

- `/oldApp` => (return index.html for old version)
- `/*`      => (all files and apis of using old version app)
- `/api/*`  => (for Angular apis)

I know, its complicated but I can change only Angular app.

I used lastly this *ngsw.config.json* but it isn't work too.

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js",
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "oldApp",
      "urls": [
        "/oldApp/**",
        "/**"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "max-size": 0,
        "maxAge": "0u",
        "strategy": "freshness"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "api",
      "urls": [
        "/api/**"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "max-size": 0,
        "maxAge": "0u",
        "strategy": "freshness"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Hey man, may i just share that you should be weary of caching the index.html file because when you deploy to production you need the index.html file to always update because of the cache busting  paths i.e. `<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.ae190ae28384aeef836c.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.1c4062b4c115efee62a1.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.573ff49a6fe5da96e0f7.js"></script>` those unique paths need to update whenever you  publish new built code.

Comment: if those scripts are cached in the index.html it will cause the app to load a blank screen.

Comment: Angular create *ngsw.json* file. This file contains hashes. Angular use this hashes. As far as i know, If the app has any update, Angular reload all updated files and *index.html*

Comment: cool just test it out. i had some issues in production with using a the ngsw-config.json file to cache the index.html before.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. This is my first Service Worker job. I will check it this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wrote my own service worker script. Firstly, I wrote script running after compilation. The script read all compiled file names and create new service worker js file. Secondly, I wrote `RegisterSWService` inside Angular. `RegisterSWService` register file which created after compilation.